# converting html tags and the content to string

Tags: javascript

my question is I need to create a string from the result of event.content. Event.content returns me an entry including html tags. I can use it like container.innerHTML = event.content. I need the event.content as a string. I tried to do something like this:

```
var a = '' + event.content;
```

But it doesn't work. Here the result of event.content:

```
<img src="http://image.weather.com/web/common/wxicons/31/30.gif?12122006" alt="" />Partly Cloudy, and 84 &deg; F. For more details?
```

I can't convert this into string in javascript. Is it possible? I also tried String(event.content). Ok I put my whole code.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>  
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Hava Durumu</title>  

 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  google.load("feeds", "1");
function havabas(){

   var feed = new google.feeds.Feed("http://rss.weather.com/weather/rss/local/TUXX0014? cm_ven=LWO&cm_cat=rss&par=LWO_rss");
  feed.load(function(result) {
    if (!result.error) {
        var entry = result.feed.entries[0];
        var container = document.getElementById("weather");
        var c = entry.content;

        var regex = /<img.*?src="(.*?)".*?>.*?([0-9]+\s*&deg;)/;
        var results = regex.exec(entry.content);
        var html = '<img src= ' + results[1] + ' alt="" /> ' + results[2];

      container.innerHTML = html;

    }
  });
}

function initialize() {
havabas();
setInterval(function(){havabas()},2000);
}
google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="weather"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks to me like `event.content` is already a string. What exactly "does not work"?

Comment: var results = regex.exec(event.content);
Here, it doesn't work. But when I assign <img src..... > to a variable like var a = ' <img src ... >'; I can use it inside exec.

Comment: And again, what exactly "does not work"? Are you getting an error? Or does it not return the result you want? What is `regex`? What does `console.dir(event.content)` or `typeof event.content` give you? If we don't know what `event.content` is, then we cannot help you. HTML can only exist inside JavaScript as strings anyway, so your question is a bit confusing.

Comment: I'm using google feed api, and it returns me RSS feeds. I'm getting content of first feed and this is event.content. You can see what is the event.content on the second piece of code. Starts with <img src...>

Comment: `typeof c` yields `string`, so `c` **is already a string**. Your problem seems to be that your regular expression is not matching it.

Comment: but I tried with the string and it is working. I mean I used <img src ....> Then how is this working?

Comment: When I inspect the string, I see `°`, not `&deg;`, hence your expression does not match.

Comment: I used this var regex = /<img.*?src="(.*?)".*?>.*?([0-9]+\s*&deg;\s*[CF])/; still same i can't see naything

Comment: Obviously your problem is not that `c` is not a string, because it is a string. The next thing you are doing is trying to match it with a regular expression, which fails (`regex.test(c)` returns `false`). So I assume you actually want to match it, which it does if you replace `&deg;` with `°`: http://jsfiddle.net/N5Ndn/. You  have to look at the data you get, the string does **not** contain `&deg;`.

Comment: oooh damn you are right but still don't idea why it is wrong to use &def instead of °. I think I should think each item as a char

Comment: `&deg;` is the *HTML entity* for `°`, JavaScript does not interpret HTML entities, it will take the characters literally, i.e. it will look for the characters `&`, `d`, `e`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is invalid. It does not match the string from `entry.content`. The reason for this is `&deg;`. Change your code to this:

```
var regex = /<img.*?src="(.*?)".*?>.*?([0-9]+)/;
var results = regex.exec(entry.content);
var html = '<img src= ' + results[1] + ' alt="" /> ' + results[2] + ' &deg;';
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ebokah/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you forgot to escape either the sigle quotes or double quotes with a backlash? This is a valid string -

```
var string="<img src=\"http://image.weather.com/web/common/wxicons/31/30.gif?12122006\"     alt=\"\" />Partly Cloudy, and 84 &deg; F. For more details?";
```

Comment: well the problem is event.content returns this <img src ...> It is not hardcoded. It is working in this way. But I need to use event.content not <img src...>

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE> New Document </TITLE>
<META NAME="Generator" CONTENT="EditPlus">
<META NAME="Author" CONTENT="">
<META NAME="Keywords" CONTENT="">
<META NAME="Description" CONTENT="">
</HEAD>
<script>
function get1()
{

var i='<img src="http://image.weather.com/web/common/wxicons/31/30.gif?12122006" alt="" />Partly Cloudy, and 84 &deg; F. For more details?';
var j='\'' +i+ '\'';
alert(j);
}
</script>
<BODY onload='get1();'>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Please try this